# Use v.clean function from GRASS in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: grass-gis, jupyter-notebook, v.clean

I want to automate a process which involves using `v.clean` tool from GRASS inside a Jupyter Notebook. I've read documentations on how to use Python with GRASS, but it seems impossible to do it or I don't understand how to do it. As far as I understand, the official GRASS documentation implies using Python inside GRASS, but I want to just run my .ipynb notebook without launching GRASS explicitly. Did I miss this part of documentation? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run GRASS from a notebook, see some resources here:
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS_Jupyter_notebooks

You can try [GRASS online in mybinder.org](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/OSGeo/grass/main?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fdoc%2Fnotebooks%2Fjupyter_example.ipynb) (be patient, can take time to build) and if you are running it locally on Windows, you may find [these notes](https://github.com/ncsu-geoforall-lab/GIS714-assignments/blob/main/GRASS_GIS_Foundations/JupyterOnWindows_Tutorial.ipynb) helpful.

Also check out a recent [workshop](https://github.com/ncsu-geoforall-lab/grass-gis-workshop-foss4gna-2023) using jupyter notebooks.